# converting pyspark datetime format into different datetime format

Tags: datetime, pyspark, timestamp

I'm using databricks to load some data.  
Within the data is a datetime.  
 The datetime field is in this format: **`2022-07-06 16:43:18.696 +0100`** 
and I want it to be in this format: **`2022-07-06T16:43:18.8000000+00:0`**. 
 I'm ultimately converting the data into JSON to be fed into an API (which I've done), so the field is going to be converted into a string.  I'm just having difficulty getting the datetime into the desired format using pyspark. The API call code is completed but errors out because it is expecting the datetime field to be in the desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the `to_utc_timestamp` function.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_utc_timestamp, date_format

df = [
    {"Category": "A", "date": "2022-07-06 16:43:18.696 +0100", "Indictor": 1},
    {"Category": "A", "date": "2022-07-06 16:43:18.696 +0200", "Indictor": 0},
    {"Category": "A", "date": "2022-07-06 16:43:18.696 +0300", "Indictor": 1},
    {"Category": "A", "date": "2022-07-06 16:43:18.696 +0400", "Indictor": 1},
    {"Category": "A", "date": "2022-07-06 16:43:18.696 +0500", "Indictor": 1},
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

# Convert the datetime field to the desired format
converted_data = df.withColumn(
    "date",
    date_format(
        to_utc_timestamp(df["date"], "GMT"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'+00:0'"
    ),
)

# Show the converted data
converted_data.show(truncate=False)
```

**Result**

```
+--------+--------+--------------------------------+
|Category|Indictor|date                            |
+--------+--------+--------------------------------+
|A       |1       |2022-07-06T15:43:18.6960000+00:0|
|A       |0       |2022-07-06T14:43:18.6960000+00:0|
|A       |1       |2022-07-06T13:43:18.6960000+00:0|
|A       |1       |2022-07-06T12:43:18.6960000+00:0|
|A       |1       |2022-07-06T11:43:18.6960000+00:0|
+--------+--------+--------------------------------+
```

Also a note, the `+0100` in the timestamp implies the timezone offset. So its 1 hour ahead of the UTC time. Which from your required format your API needs a UTC timezone.